# What is role of the suite function in Mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I read the book Web Development with Node.js and Express. And there is used the function `suite()`.

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
suite('tests', function () {
  // set of tests
});
```

I don't understand where it comes from. I can't find any documentation about this function.
Seems that it looks and has same functionality like the `describe()` function in Mocha.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Mocha supports several different ways of writing tests ([interfaces](https://mochajs.org/#interfaces)) so that you can choose a style that suits your methodology.  `describe()` and `suite()` essentially do the same thing: they let you label and group together a set of tests; the grouped tests are organised under a common label in the output and can use common setup and teardown functions.

The choice of which function to use depends on whether you are using a Behaviour Driven Development (BDD) methodology (where you `describe()` the behaviour you want `it()` to do), or Test Driven Development (TDD), where you define a `suite()` of `test()`s you want your code to pass.  You should choose whichever style you feel makes your code more readable.

Here's a blog explaining [the Difference Between TDD and BDD](https://joshldavis.com/2013/05/27/difference-between-tdd-and-bdd/) with regard to test design.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation can be found on the mocha website: https://mochajs.org/#tdd

`suite` is the TDD version of `describe`. You generally use it to describe and isolate the functionality/features/behaviour that you are going to test.